# Как перейти с GA3 на GA4?

Tags: веб-программирование, google-analytics, gtm

Поддержка GA3 скоро прекратится.
Мне нужно перевести сайт на GA4 с GA3.
Но нужно это сделать так, чтобы старый GA3 ещё работал.

Вопрос в том, как это сделать?

GTM подключен как тег script в веб приложении.
Я правильно вообще понимаю, что создаётся некий кабинет (GA), и к этому кабинету подключается GTM как источник данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переход с `Google Analytics 3` (GA3) на `Google Analytics 4` (GA4) может быть немного сложным процессом, но вот общая последовательность шагов:

1. Создайте новый аккаунт `Google Analytics 4`. Это можно сделать, зайдя на страницу `Google Analytics` и выбрав опцию "Создать новый аккаунт".
2. Настройте свой новый аккаунт GA4. Здесь вам потребуется ввести информацию о своем сайте и связать его с вашим аккаунтом GA3.
3. Добавьте код отслеживания GA4 на свой сайт. Вы можете использовать `Google Tag Manager` для этого или добавить код отслеживания напрямую на свой сайт.
4. Настройте цели и события в GA4. Цели и события - это способы измерения производительности вашего сайта и определения того, как пользователи взаимодействуют с вашим контентом.
5. Импортируйте данные из GA3 в GA4. Для этого вам потребуется использовать инструменты миграции данных, которые предоставляются `Google Analytics`.

Ответ на комментарий Alexander:

Если у вас уже есть настроенный тег `Google Analytics 4` и идентификатор `Google Tag Manager`, который подключен к вашему сайту, то скорее всего вам не нужно ничего менять в коде самого сайта.

Однако, чтобы убедиться, что ваш тег GA4 правильно установлен и работает, вы можете провести тестирование. Для этого вы можете воспользоваться инструментом `Google Tag Assistant`, который позволяет проверить установку тегов и наличие ошибок.

Вам также стоит проверить настройки целей и событий в вашем аккаунте GA4, чтобы убедиться, что они настроены правильно и отражают взаимодействие пользователей с вашим сайтом.

Наконец, не забудьте настроить импорт данных из вашего старого GA3 аккаунта в GA4, если вы хотите продолжать использовать данные из прошлых периодов.

Comment: У меня уже есть GA4 аккаунт, тег (<script>) и идентификатор GTM, подключенный к сайту. Нужно ли мне что-то менять в самом коде моего сайта?

Comment: @Alexander Ответ дополнил на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Импортируйте данные из GA3 в GA4. Для этого вам потребуется использовать инструменты миграции данных, которые предоставляются Google Analytics. Какие именно?

Answer (score 0):

Для перехода мне потребовалось поменять схему отсылаемых в аналитику данных.

Например:

Было:

```js
window.dataLayer.push({ event: 'event_name', ...data })
```

Стало:

```js
window.dataLayer.push({ event: 'event_name', ecommerce: { ...data }})
```

Я не знаю, связано ли эти изменения с тем, что переход (настройку GA4) мы отдали на аутсорс, а реализацию в коде делали сами, но тем не менее.

Способ подключения, скрипт тега, код менять не пришлось.